# get contents of javascript value into a php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, echo

i have a client who is required to use specific tracking that is only made available through javascript. he wants to be able to capture the exact same information being printed on the client side.

how can i add this into the existing php script to add the data into the database? my only idea was to echo the javascript directly inside the main script, but i can't seem to figure out how to get the values out of the php echo.

any ideas?

Comment: What does "being passed on through the javascript" mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: sorry bad terminology i'll edit. what i meant was the data i need is printed from the required javascript. so i'm trying to print it, capture it, then store it in a variable.

Comment: "Printed"?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: The only way I can think of to get that information back to the server is by sending it in an Ajax request. If you can, just write some javascript to prepare the information and then send it to a php script to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it to the server using a dummy image.

```
document.write('<img src="file.php?foo=value1?bar=value2&...">');
```

contents of file.php

```
<?PHP 
Header("Content-type: image/png"); 

do something with $_GET['foo']

?>
```

It's not the best way, but it's fast and it will work.

Comment: yea this is pretty much what i was trying to do. i was even thinking to screen scrape the information but this is so much easier. it's a really nice trick. i know others were looking for something similar too thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really possible, you'd need to do an AJAX call to get something similar.

I suggest implementing the code in PHP directly rather then reliying on Javascript for data.

Comment: that's the problem. i can ONLY generate the data from javascript.

Comment: The JavaScript code runs on the client browser, thousands of miles away from the server where the PHP code runs. Your only choice is ajax.

Comment: @john: AJAX is as simple as submitting a form if you use a decent toolkit such as jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: I concur. AJAX is the way to exchange browser-side data (javascript) with the server-side script of your choice (PHP, ASP etc.)

Comment: Why can you only generate the data from Javascript? What do you need in Javascript that is not in PHP? (Unless you want users to mine bitcoins for you, I don't see why)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because **client-side script** can NOT interact directly with **server-side script**, therefore it requires you to have a "transporter" in the between, which is AJAX. Have a look at [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it's tiny, sweet and powerful.

But assume there is a small chunk of information, and it's not very confidential, I can suggest you to do this way, using cookies. People don't usually take advantage of cookies.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.cookie = 'info='+information; expires=Mon, 19 Jul 201110:00:00 UTC; path=/';
</script>
```

In PHP file

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIES['info'])) {
   $information= intval($_COOKIES['info']);
}
?>
```

Once you finish getting the information, you can delete that cookies.